# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I have a Spring boot application.
spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.0.RELEASE

I'm trying to get a list of objects and expect to get something like this:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "role": "MASTER",
            "module": "USER_EDIT",
            "permissions": [
                 "READ", "WRITE"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "total": 1
}
```

But I receive an exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: 
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum (through reference chain: com.myproject.dto.ListDto["items"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.myproject.dto.PermissionDto["permissions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
...
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum (through reference chain: com.myproject.dto.ListDto["items"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.myproject.dto.PermissionDto["permissions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:397)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:368)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:338)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(IndexedListSerializer.java:148)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.EnumSerializer.serialize(EnumSerializer.java:27)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(IndexedListSerializer.java:142)
...
```

**Api method**:

```
@GetMapping
public ListDto<PermissionDto> permissions() {
    return new ListDto<>(permissionsService.list(), permissionsService.count());
}
```

**ListDto**:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ListDto<T> {
    private List<T> items;
    private long total;
}
```

**PermissionDto**:

```
@Data
public class PermissionDto {
    private Role role;
    private Module module;
    private List<Permission> permissions;
}
```

**Permission**:

```
public enum Permission {
    READ,
    WRITE,
    UPDATE,
    DELETE;
}
```

Comment: There are lots of examples like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums).
Probably you are missing something like `@JsonValue` on your `Enum`.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Turns out that the error is actually describing what is going on: There are really strings inside `List<Permission> permissions`.
Jackson and other mappers do some weird stuff under the hood, including lots of casting.

In my case, the problem was actually in the deserialization stage that fills the list with objects. I was using jackson to read values into this list like this:

```
objectMapper.readValue(listAsString, List.class)
```

instead, you should do this:

```
objectMapper.readValue(listAsString, Permission[].class)
```

This ensures that the mapper doesn't try to cast the values to strings in deserialization, and then the values are of the correct type when serialized back to json.